Oracle REGEXP_SUBSTR generated subquery
I have query in an XML file to generate a report, then I upload it to server. When I call it, the query makes a subquery that caused the error: 'missing expression'
Here is my original query:
SELECT cm.policy_code, cm.apply_code, ta.agent_code, cm.organ_id,
        SUM(pf.fee_amount) AS fee_amount,
        MIN(pf.insert_time) AS insert_time,
        MIN(pf.pay_mode) AS pay_mode,
        (select PHONE_NUMBER  
          from ais.e_otp
          where e_app_id=ep.E_POLICY_ID and otp_type=1 and app_type=1
          order by INSERT_DATE desc
          FETCH  first 1 rows only) OTP_PHONE_NUMBER,
        (select SEND_DATE  
          from ais.e_otp
          where e_app_id=ep.E_POLICY_ID and otp_type=1 and app_type=1
          order by INSERT_DATE desc
          FETCH  first 1 rows only) OTP_SEND_DATE,
          pf.ENTRY_CODE
        FROM t_contract_master cm, 
          t_agent ta,
          t_policy_fee pf,
          ais.t_eapp_policy ep
        WHERE ta.agent_id = cm.agent_id
          AND pf.policy_id = cm.policy_id
          AND ep.E_APPLICATION_ID = cm.apply_code
          AND pf.fee_type IN (11, 169)
          and cm.policy_code in 
          (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (:i_policy_code,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
                  FROM DUAL 
                      CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(:i_policy_code,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
        group by cm.policy_code, cm.apply_code, ta.agent_code,cm.organ_id,ep.E_POLICY_ID,pf.ENTRY_CODE

When I pass a comma-separated list, inside the REGEPX_SUBSTR has generated a subquery SELECT with the parameter.
SELECT cm.policy_code, cm.apply_code, ta.agent_code, cm.organ_id,
        SUM(pf.fee_amount) AS fee_amount,
        MIN(pf.insert_time) AS insert_time,
        MIN(pf.pay_mode) AS pay_mode,
        (select PHONE_NUMBER
          from ais.e_otp
          where e_app_id=ep.E_POLICY_ID and otp_type=1 and app_type=1
          order by INSERT_DATE desc
          FETCH  first 1 rows only) OTP_PHONE_NUMBER,
        (select SEND_DATE
          from ais.e_otp
          where e_app_id=ep.E_POLICY_ID and otp_type=1 and app_type=1
          order by INSERT_DATE desc
          FETCH  first 1 rows only) OTP_SEND_DATE,
          pf.ENTRY_CODE
        FROM t_contract_master cm,
          t_agent ta,
          t_policy_fee pf,
          ais.t_eapp_policy ep
        WHERE ta.agent_id = cm.agent_id
          AND pf.policy_id = cm.policy_id
          AND ep.E_APPLICATION_ID = cm.apply_code
          AND pf.fee_type IN (11, 169)
          AND cm.policy_code IN
          (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(SELECT '010038659083008' i_policy_code_1 ,'010038658976008' i_policy_code_2 ,'010038483841008' i_policy_code_3  FROM DUAL,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
                  FROM DUAL
                      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(SELECT '010038659083008' i_policy_code_1 ,'010038658976008' i_policy_code_2 ,'010038483841008' i_policy_code_3  FROM DUAL,',') + 1)policy_codes
        group by cm.policy_code, cm.apply_code, ta.agent_code,cm.organ_id,ep.E_POLICY_ID,pf.ENTRY_CODE

which gets:
Error Msg = ORA-00936: missing expression

How should I correct it?

Please try to improve the code format in the question so people can help you better.

You haven't shown what is replacing the bind variable i_policy_code with SELECT '010038659083008' i_policy_code_1 ,'010038658976008' i_policy_code_2 ,'010038483841008' i_policy_code_3  FROM DUAL, or why - the original query has a bind variable but you aren't binding anything, you're substituting that instead, which is weird in itself; but then the subquery being used for the substitution makes no sense in that context. The problem isn't in the code you've shown, it's in whatever is generating that code, and we can't see that.


SELECT '010038659083008' i_policy_code_1 ,'010038658976008' i_policy_code_2 ,'010038483841008' i_policy_code_3  FROM DUAL is wrong as there should not be any substitution but if there was it should be the literal '010038659083008,010038658976008,010038483841008' and not a sub-query. If whatever pre-processor you are using is treating bind variable as if they are substitution variables then you probably need to find a better pre-processor or else find some setting that stops it from performing substitutions and will actually bind variables to a parameterised query; however, you do not give any details of what is making the substitution so we cannot help with that.
)policy_codes is a syntax error and should just be ), as it is in the original query; again this appears to be something your pre-processor has added and you give no details of what you are using to perform the pre-processing.

Since you are using a version that supports the FETCH syntax, you should also be able to use LATERAL joins and can rewrite the code using ANSI joins (rather than the legacy comma-joins) as:
SELECT cm.policy_code,
       cm.apply_code,
       ta.agent_code,
       cm.organ_id,
       SUM(pf.fee_amount) AS fee_amount,
       MIN(pf.insert_time) AS insert_time,
       MIN(pf.pay_mode) AS pay_mode,
       MIN(otp.phone_number) AS OTP_PHONE_NUMBER,
       MIN(otp.SEND_DATE) AS OTP_SEND_DATE,
       pf.ENTRY_CODE
FROM   t_contract_master cm
       INNER JOIN t_agent ta
       ON ta.agent_id = cm.agent_id
       INNER JOIN t_policy_fee pf
       ON pf.policy_id = cm.policy_id
       INNER JOIN ais.t_eapp_policy ep
       ON ep.E_APPLICATION_ID = cm.apply_code
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
         select PHONE_NUMBER, SEND_DATE
         from   ais.e_otp
         where  e_app_id = ep.E_POLICY_ID
         and    otp_type = 1
         and    app_type = 1
         order by INSERT_DATE desc
         FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
       ) otp
       ON (1 = 1)
WHERE  pf.fee_type IN (11, 169)
AND    cm.policy_code IN (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
                                   '010038659083008,010038658976008,010038483841008',
                                   '[^,]+',
                                   1,
                                   LEVEL
                                 )
                          FROM   DUAL
                          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(
                                                '010038659083008,010038658976008,010038483841008',
                                                ','
                                              ) + 1
                        )
group by
       cm.policy_code,
       cm.apply_code,
       ta.agent_code,
       cm.organ_id,
       ep.E_POLICY_ID,
       pf.ENTRY_CODE

Or you can use :i_policy_code instead of the string literal (assuming that you can use it as a bind variable and not a substitution variable).

I made it. In the cm.policy_code IN clause, I change to this: [WHERE  pf.fee_type IN (11, 169)
AND  EXISTS (select 1 from (:i_policy_code ) tmp where tmp.i_policy_code_1 = cm.policy_code)]

@GiangTruong While that may have solved your problem, :variable is a bind variable and normally passes a value. Whatever pre-prcessor you are using is NOT doing that and is treating :variable as a substitution variable and is inserting a SELECT statement rather than binding a value; since you haven't told us what you are using as a pre-processor its very difficult to help you. But, if you've solved the problem then maybe the question is academic.
